# create a List<string> from a list, breaking on last comma

Tags: c#

I need to split a string on the last comma. I have this which works, if there is only one comma

```
 var ident = identNumbers.Split(',').ToList();
```

my string is being formatted using Jquery/CSS and is derived from a JSON string, which doesn't contain any new line characters.

the string looks like:

```
Special Interest Entity (SIE) / Sanctions Lists / State Owned Company,Special Interest Entity (SIE) / Enhanced Country Risk / State Owned Company
```

and i need to end up with a list that looks like this:

- Special Interest Entity (SIE) / Sanctions Lists / State Owned Company
- Special Interest Entity (SIE) / Enhanced Country Risk / State Owned Company

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: Why do you show a sample which works with your current approach? Instead show an example where this approach doesn't work.

Comment: can you give an example that show the problem ? seem like your code should do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you need something like this:

```
var input = "foo, bar, sample1, sample2 sample3";
var last = input.LastIndexOf(',');
var result = new[] {input.Substring(0, last), input.Substring(last+1).Trim()};
```

`result` contains two elements: `"foo, bar, sample1"` and `"sample2 sample3"`